# Log written from Camel route before split is complete

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

I have a Camel route which takes in a large xml file, splits it, and sends it to another endpoint for processing.

```
from("file:data/in?readLock=markerFile")
        .log("File has been picked and sent to Split")
        .to("log:INFO?showHeaders=true&showProperties=true&multiline=true")
        .split(body().tokenizeXML("doc","response")).streaming()
            .to("seda:fromSplit?size=70000")   
        .end()
        .log("File has been completely split.");
```

In the route, I have set a log saying "File has been completely split." after the entire file has been split. However, this log is written at the beginning itself, and does not wait for the entire split to be completed. Why is this happening?

Comment: `seda` is asynchronous.

Comment: Using `direct` is taking a lot of time, since the file in question contains around 35000 records. Is there any way to process the file efficiently by synchronously?

Comment: You can look at `waitForTaskToComplete=Always` on seda producer side and `concurrentConsumers` on consumer side.

Answer (score 0):

Did you give a try to parallelProcessing option ?